# How can I define Generic type : type as property name typescript

Tags: typescript

How can I define a generic type `GetAppActions` if `T` equals `trigger` data property only shows `trigger` and vice versa

```
type GetAppActionType = 'trigger' | 'action'
interface AppActionInputField {}

type GetAppActions<T = GetAppActionType> = {
    data: {
        action: { inputFields: AppActionInputField[] }
        trigger: { inputFields: AppActionInputField[] }
    }
    type: T
}
```

Comment: What if `T` is a union type like `'trigger' | 'action'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content)

```js
interface AppActionInputField {}

type GetAppActions<T extends "trigger"|"action"> = {
    data: {
        [K in T]: { inputFields: AppActionInputField[] }
    },
    type: T
}

const test: GetAppActions<"trigger"> = {
    data: {
        trigger: { inputFields: [{}] }
    },
    type: "trigger"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAd2oWYB7EASRHQFcwAxYCAGwBNkBvAXwChWwBPdFAcQjAYsOfCADOAHgAqyCAA9IIOmOQAiMFGABzLdFUAfVYlwFVAPmQBeJq2R3kdOGDgAuG-Y-IA2gGlkoZCkAXTdGfxJyKlplNyFsEyIIymp6LyDkNg9mABpbey4eNylWNlYEAjEwZEhKt35BTHjRSXVNHT0La0Y8u0dnUJ7PDW1dKFDwsmTosTcvFnTM+xzBgog3VpG9EqA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [discrimating union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) to help you in restricting `data` property according to `type`.

Basically, this acts as a `switch` for your types.

```
interface AppActionInputField { }

type GetAppActions = {
  type: "trigger"
  data: {
    trigger: { inputFields: AppActionInputField[] }
  }
} | {
  type: "action",
  data: {
    action: { inputFields: AppActionInputField[] }
  }
}

type GetAppActionType = GetAppActions["type"];
// "actions" | "trigger"
```